# Angular 2 - All imports in a shared files

Tags: angular

I am dealing with some module and angular2 components, each time I create a new one, I have to pay attention to my imports.

I am trying to find a way to be able to import all of threm through a single file. Do you know if it this feasible ?

So, I would have imports.ts in which I would have:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { List } from './list';
import { ListsService } from '../shared/lists.service';
import { LoadingComponent } from '../loading/loading.component';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
```

and I just would have to import 'imports'.

Actually it does not work...
Anyone has an idea ?

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is a barrel. You can find more about it in the [Angular 2 Glossary](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/glossary.html).

Your barrel (`index.ts`) would look something like this:

```
export { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
export { List } from './list'
```

or

```
export * from './list';
export * from '../shared/lists.service';
```

Then you import from the barrel folder (if it lives in the `shared` folder you should import it by `path-to/shared`) or the barrel file (`path-to/shared/index`).

So your import would look something like this:

```
 import { List, ListsService } from 'path-to/shared';
```

Also, as mentioned in the glossary, this can also be done with angular modules. When they brought barrels to the style guide, there weren't any modules yet.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am getting:Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "shared/index"

Comment: @LaurentB you can use `shared` only then

Answer (score 0):

Create an `index.ts` and paste into is the next code

```
import { List } from './list';
import { ListsService } from '../shared/lists.service';
import { LoadingComponent } from '../loading/loading.component';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
```

After that you can use this barrel file in any component or module like this

```
import {
    List
    ListsService,
    LoadingComponent,
    Router,
    ActivatedRoute,
    Params
} from '../index.ts';
```